# Set existing git HTTPS repo to use credentials from osxkeychain

Tags: git, github

I have an existing HTTPS git repo on my machine that needs to start using osxkeychain. Everything I find online tells me to either use SSH or clone a repo and THEN set up repo to use osxkeychain for authenticating. I would like to use osxkeychain on a repo that I have already cloned locally.

Answer (score 0):

Should have listened to the internet. The best solution is switching to ssh:

https://help.github.com/articles/why-is-git-always-asking-for-my-password